# Pandas, drop duplicates but merge certain columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to drop duplicate rows based one a certain column subset, but merge some data, so it does not get removed.

```
import pandas as pd

# Example Dataframe
data = {
    "Parcel": ['001', '002', '003', '003'],
    "Res"   : ['Henry', 'Nick', 'Paul', 'Bill'],
    "Bill"  : ['4,100', '2,300', '5,200', '4,000'],
    "Year"  : ['1995', '1990', '2008', '2008']
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=data)
```

| Parcel | Res | Bill | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Henry | 4,100 | 1995 |
| 002 | Nick | 2,300 | 1990 |
| 003 | Paul | 5,200 | 2008 |
| 003 | Bill | 4,000 | 2008 |

Some pseudo code would look something like this:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Parcel', keep_data=['Res', 'Bill'])
```

| Parcel | Res | Bill | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Henry | 4,100 | 1995 |
| 002 | Nick | 2,300 | 1990 |
| 003 | Paul, Bill | 5,200, 4,000 | 2008 |

I'm not sure where to begin with this, but any tips as to where to look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.groupby` with `.agg`:

```
df = (
    df.groupby("Parcel")
    .agg({"Res": ", ".join, "Bill": ", ".join, "Year": "first"})
    .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Parcel         Res          Bill  Year
0    001       Henry         4,100  1995
1    002        Nick         2,300  1990
2    003  Paul, Bill  5,200, 4,000  2008
```

---

EDIT: If you have many columns, you can aggregate all values by "first" and then update the dataframe:

```
g = df.groupby("Parcel")
x = g.agg("first")
x.update(g.agg({"Res": ", ".join, "Bill": ", ".join}))
print(x.reset_index())

  Parcel         Res          Bill  Year
0    001       Henry         4,100  1995
1    002        Nick         2,300  1990
2    003  Paul, Bill  5,200, 4,000  2008
```

Comment: This works, but how would I expand this for more than 3 columns. Current I am working with 10 columns, and doing ```"col_xx" : "first"``` is tedious. Could I pass ```list(df[3:]) : "first" ```?

Comment: Thank you! This is amazingly helpful!